# How to make TeamCity build fail if artifacts are not found?

Tags: build, teamcity, artifacts

Is it posible to fail TeamCity builds if artifacts are not found? I mean without writing any special script, i.e. does TeamCity has such built-in functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're going to have to implement that functionality into your build script.

i.e. if you are using MSBUILD .. after everything is complete run the following command:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('someArtifact.txt')" Text="Error!!! Artifact doesn't exist" />
```

Answer (score 6):

In TeamCity 7.x you can catch this using a build failure condition. You can add a condition in your build configuration to fail on specific text found in a build log.

For example fail on text:

```
    Artifacts path file.txt not found
```

This works, I use it in my builds to catch missing artifacts.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to do this in TeamCity 2019.1.5 (build 66605). No success. Anything you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answer here.
You can add regex expression that will discover this in the build log and will fail the test:

```
^Artifacts path '.*' not found$
```

[image]
It is also recommended to add meaningful error message, such as:

```
Failed to find artifact to publish
```